# my xcode version is 13 and not support the collectionView below method

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var shoppingapp:[String] = ["cher","sale Small","shoes"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

   //this function is not working in my xcode 13 not calle this function 
# func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
# return shoppingapp.count
#     }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
        
        cell.shoppinfappimage.image = UIImage(named: shoppingapp[indexPath.row] + ".jpeg")
        cell.shoppinfappimage.layer.cornerRadius=50.0
        return cell
    }

}
```

I don't know which other method is there I am learning and practical in iOS application development****

Comment: did you add datasource and delegate to collection view? Also why you have # in the code?

Answer (score 0):

First, please remove # from the code. Divide him into the ViewController extension.

```
    extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return shoppingapp.count
    }
        
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
        
        cell.shoppinfappimage.image = UIImage(named: shoppingapp[indexPath.row] + ".jpeg")
        cell.shoppinfappimage.layer.cornerRadius=50.0
        return cell
    }
}
```

But when I saw your code, I think you didn't declare delegate and DataSource.

```
//in viewDidLoad
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

Write the code above in viewDidLoad. So I couldn't do a lot either.

If it didn't work, try it like this.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return shoppingapp.count
}
```

I hope the writing helps me.